# Change Apache root directory

Tags: macos, permission, apache

I am having problems changing the Permissions on the "username.conf" file in the /etc/apache2/users/ folder.  It needs to have the permission of 
`-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel  298 Jun 28 16:47 username.conf`
but I am not able to achieve this.

I have tried changing the permissions with the command
`sudo chmod 644 username.conf;`
and it didn't change.

I am using this tutorial: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/forbidden-403-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-username-on-this-server/

When I check the permission of the file, it's
`-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  155 Jan 23 23:30 Owner.conf`

When I navigate to http://localhost/~Owner/ , I get 404 Not found.

Comment: At the beginning of your question, you show the file info and permissions of "username.conf", then later show the file info and permissions of "Owner.conf". Make sure that you are looking at the same file...

Comment: @ChrisMukherjee Owner.conf is my version of the username.conf.  The username.conf is from the tutorial.

Comment: The username should be the short username, which is all lowercase.  What happens if you change the file name to owner.conf, and try to access http://localhost/~owner/ ?

Answer (score 1):

The permission command `chmod 644` is actually working!

The permission of your file Owner.conf is `-rw-r--r--`.

The `chmod` command works by specifying (1) the permissions for the file owner - in this case `root`, (2) the permissions for anyone in the same group as the file owner - in this case the group is `wheel`, and then (3) the permissions for everybody else (global permissions).

For each of the three above groups of users, the possible permissions are `r`ead, `w`rite, and e`x`ecute. Full permissions would look like this: `-rwxrwxrwx`.

The permissions are specified using binary notation. `1` means the permission should be set, and `0` means it should not be.

Thus, setting chmod 644 sets permissions `6` - or `110` in binary - for the file owner, and `4` - or `100` in binary - for the group and for everybody else.

This creates the permission string `-110100100`. This translates to: `-rw-r--r--`.

Note that in your question above, the `username.conf` and `Owner.conf` both do have permissions of `644`.

Comment: Then why my .conf file is not 298 like the tutorial conf file.  Why is it I cannot navigate to http://localhost/~Owner/

Thanks

Comment: 298 is the size of the file. Your file is 155 MB, and the tutorial file is 298 MB. The tutorial mentions a **403** error, which is a permission error. You are getting a **404** error, which means that the file is not found. Are you sure that your Owner.conf file is in the right directory?

Comment: Ok, I thought that it was the permission code. the conf file is in the apache2/user folder.  Here is the [httpd](http://pastie.org/private/kyvapmflkd1srjyfacifsw) file, my [conf](http://pastie.org/private/ifn5ao7i2fpp1o0ruw2ukg) file, and the [httpd-user](http://pastie.org/private/vawghravkkvasmegqehgta)

Comment: Edit to my comment above, the file sizes are in Bytes, not MB.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not willing to do all the work for you. As far as this question goes, I feel as though I have answered the question in a sufficiently clear and detailed manner. If you have a new question, feel free to ask a new question (though I believe that http://stackoverflow.com/ might be a better fit for your questions). I would advise you to take the time to do some research online first to see if the solution to your problem already exists. Best of luck!